# php mcrypt function error --- unsuccessful decryption in wamp

Tags: php, encryption

I using php mcrypt function to do decryption of my text file.

1.txt

```
1
2
3
```

I use file() function to put value in array and set up decryption function in d.php.

d.php

```
<?php
function encryptData($array){
$key = "secret key";
$noenarray = $array;
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
foreach ($noenarray as $k => $value) {
    $cryptarray[$k] = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key,$noenarray[$value], MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
}
return $cryptarray;
}

function decryptData($array){
$key = "secret key";
$cryptarray = $array;
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
foreach ($cryptarray as $k => $value) {
    $decryptarray[$k] = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key,$cryptarray[$value], MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
}
return $decryptarray;
}

function test($name){
$path = "$name.txt";
$i = file($path);
$di = decryptData($i);
$ei=encryptData($di);
echo "1.txt";
echo "<br>";
print_r($i);
echo "<br>";
echo "decrypt 1.txt";
echo "<br>";
print_r($di);
echo "<br>";
echo "encrypt 1.txt";
echo "<br>";
print_r($ei);
}

test(1);
?>
```

I try to run the code , but the decryption output of 1,2,3 is same.

**Update:**
I also try to encrypt the decrypted array , then output is not true.

output of 1.php

```
1.txt
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) 
decrypt 1.txt
Array ( [0] => ÆÃ5oj¨K ¯«^yäô½ô‘+Çk2äwâÔ [1] => ÆÃ5oj¨K ¯«^yäô½ô‘+Çk2äwâÔ [2] => ÆÃ5oj¨K ¯«^yäô½ô‘+Çk2äwâÔ )
encrypt 1.txt
Array ( [0] => NÉ™ "hI†¢'„Ÿ]6ŸU9óþ¸ÃÝgo¯èÂ [1] => NÉ™ "hI†¢'„Ÿ]6ŸU9óþ¸ÃÝgo¯èÂ [2] => NÉ™ "hI†¢'„Ÿ]6ŸU9óþ¸ÃÝgo¯èÂ )
```

What wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

`1` is not a valid ciphertext for Rijndael-256 in ECB mode. Ciphertexts must be a multiple of block size long which is n*32 bytes.

**Perhaps you meant to first encrypt and *then* decrypt your file.** Note that encrypted data may contain every possible byte since it is binary. So it may every contain `\n` bytes. This means that you cannot read the data line wise for decryption. You need either to encrypt the whole file in a single pass or encode the file parts after encryption so that it can't contain a newline character.

Another problem is your secret key. It has to be either 16, 24 or 32 bytes long. mcrypt will gladly take an incomplete key, but you will run into problems with other good implementations that expect that the key is of a certain size. AFAIK, mcrypt fills the given key with 0x00 bytes until a valid key size is reached.

Furthermore, the ECB mode doesn't support an IV, so there is no need to create one. But ECB is also not semantically secure. You should at least use CBC mode and if possible use an authenticated mode which mcrypt doesn't provide.

Comment: How can I change the code to encrypt and decrypt the text file?

Comment: For starters `$ei=encryptData($i); $di = decryptData($ei);`. Then use `file_get_contents()` instead of `file()`. You get the file as a string back, so you don't need to iterate in the encrypt and decrypt functions.

Comment: i use array format to write encrypt and decrypt functions, like mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key,$noenarray[$value], MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv); , I need to change it to string format?